# Handle text that looks like scientific number

Tags: excel, vba

Excel handle text look like scientific number as a number.
Example:

cell A1 (text):   325E0111

, cell A2 (number): 12345678

, cell A3 (text):   HelloWorld

My objective is to read these text, along with numbers, into an array in Excel VBA. Then paste it into another worksheet.

In Excel VBA DO NOT want to use select, copy and paste due to potential error.

If I use "value", "value2", 325E0111 is converted to number 3.25+E113.

If I use "text", error occur as 12345678 is a number.

Any advice? Is it a known Excel bug?

Comment: How is the Array declared?

Comment: You can read a text and format it into a number using the text function: `WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheets(1).Cells(3,2), "#")`.

Comment: Example code: It can pass through both numbers and text correctly, but would have error when the text appears like a scientific expression. ``
`Sub Test1()` `a = WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), "#")` `b = WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1), "#")` `d = WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1), "#")` `Sheets(1).Cells(5, 1) = a` `Sheets(1).Cells(6, 1) = b` `Sheets(1).Cells(7, 1) = d` `End Sub`